# CSS Grid: Paragraph tag breaking layout

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I was creating a one column layout using grid (flexbox for a nested collection of thumbs within the grid).

Everything was fine until I added the paragraph?

[image]

This is prior to that mess:
[image]

This is my SCSS:

```
@import 'base.scss';
@import 'typography.scss';
.modal {
    /* Overlay */
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /* Black */
    background: $color-black;
    mix-blend-mode: normal;
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 1;
}

.details {
    position: fixed;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 5% 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "close-button" "title-price" "image" "description";
    padding-top: 2%;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    /* Modal Shadow */
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    .closeBtn {
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 3%;
        justify-self: end;
        margin-right: 6%;
    }
    @include small-only {
        top: 2%;
        height: 95%;
        left: 30px;
        right: 30px;
    }
    @include medium {
        top: 2%;
        height: 95%;
        left: 51px;
        right: 51px;
        /* White */
    }
    @include large {
        /* Background */
        height: 95%;
        left: 135px;
        right: 135px;
        /* White */
    }
}

.modalTemplate {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    @include small-only {
        grid-template-rows: 10%;
        /* new */
        .title {
            @include heading
        }
        .price {
            margin-top: 1%;
            @include price
        }
        .image {
            margin-top: 5%;
            height: 305px;
            width: 267px;
            justify-self: center;
            /* vertical centering */
        }
        .imageThumbContainer {
            margin-top: 3%;
            height: auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            .imageThumbs {
                height: 60px;
                width: 60px;
                border-radius: 0px;
            }
        }
        .description {
            @include body;
            flex: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my template, I'm using `JSX`:

```
<div className={modal.modalTemplate}>
  <header>
    <h2 className={modal.title}>{title}</h2>
    <span className={modal.price}>${finalPrice}</span>
  </header>
  <img className={modal.image} src={imageSrc} alt={title} />
  <div className={modal.imageThumbContainer}>
    {images.map(image => image)}
  </div>
  <p className={modal.description}>
    DESCRIPTION:{' '}
    {images[0] != undefined
      ? images[0].props['data-description']
      : null}
  </p>
```

Can someone explain why adding a paragraph is doing this? What was surprising I actually changed the `display` property and made it a block level element and changed the width to `100%` I would think that would have made it the same width as its parent. But obviously that didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because till you added the paragraph all the other elements were smaller than main image, for which you have specified a `width`. Add the same `width` as `max-width` for the paragraph.

```css
.description {
    @include body;
    flex: 1;
    display:block;
    max-width: 267px;
}
```